# snippet.cgi — as many as 10 at a time in rapid succession…

Tags: safari, data-transfer

Some sites, just navigating to them, in Safari, I have not tested in any other browsers, will auto download a file called `snippet.cgi` to your `~/Downloads` folder.

I just went to www.cliftonchilliclub.co.uk/ and merely loading the page shoved 6 `snippet.cgi` files to my `~/Downloads` folder.  The OS renames them sequentially. `snippet.cgi`, `snippet-1.cgi`, `snippet-2.cgi`, `snippet-3.cgi`.

Opening `snippet.cgi` in [TextMate](http://macromates.com) ( Basic Mac OS X Text Eitor ) and the file contains "Cant get component".

Here is a gist of what is going on:
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/143323b1553bfd502a08

Here is the raw data:

```
me@foonty ~ $cd Downloads/
me@foonty Downloads $ls -la
-rw-r--r--@ 1 me  staff      18 Feb  8 04:41 snippet-2.cgi
-rw-r--r--@ 1 me  staff      18 Feb  8 04:41 snippet-3.cgi
-rw-r--r--@ 1 me  staff      18 Feb  8 04:41 snippet-4.cgi
-rw-r--r--@ 1 me  staff      18 Feb  8 04:41 snippet-5.cgi
-rw-r--r--@ 1 me  staff      18 Feb  8 04:41 snippet-6.cgi
-rw-r--r--@ 1 me  staff      18 Feb  8 04:41 snippet-7.cgi
-rw-r--r--@ 1 me  staff      18 Feb  8 04:41 snippet-8.cgi
-rw-r--r--@ 1 me  staff      18 Feb  8 04:37 snippet.cgi

me@foonty Downloads $more snippet-2.cgi 
Cant get component

me@foonty Downloads $file snippet-2.cgi 
snippet-2.cgi: ASCII text, with no line terminators

me@foonty Downloads $ls -la@
drwx------+ 12 me  staff     408 Feb  8 04:41 .
drwxr-xr-x+ 32 me  staff    1088 Feb  8 01:53 ..
-rw-r--r--@  1 me  staff    6148 Feb  8 04:37 .DS_Store
    com.apple.FinderInfo        32 
-rw-r--r--@  1 me  staff      18 Feb  8 04:41 snippet-2.cgi
    com.apple.metadata:kMDItemDownloadedDate        53 
    com.apple.metadata:kMDItemWhereFroms       189 
    com.apple.quarantine        61 
-rw-r--r--@  1 me  staff      18 Feb  8 04:41 snippet-3.cgi
    com.apple.metadata:kMDItemDownloadedDate        53 
    com.apple.metadata:kMDItemWhereFroms       189 
    com.apple.quarantine        61 
-rw-r--r--@  1 me  staff      18 Feb  8 04:41 snippet-4.cgi
    com.apple.metadata:kMDItemDownloadedDate        53 
    com.apple.metadata:kMDItemWhereFroms       189 
    com.apple.quarantine        61 
-rw-r--r--@  1 me  staff      18 Feb  8 04:41 snippet-5.cgi
    com.apple.metadata:kMDItemDownloadedDate        53 
    com.apple.metadata:kMDItemWhereFroms       188 
    com.apple.quarantine        61 
-rw-r--r--@  1 me  staff      18 Feb  8 04:41 snippet-6.cgi
    com.apple.metadata:kMDItemDownloadedDate        53 
    com.apple.metadata:kMDItemWhereFroms       189 
    com.apple.quarantine        61 
-rw-r--r--@  1 me  staff      18 Feb  8 04:41 snippet-7.cgi
    com.apple.metadata:kMDItemDownloadedDate        53 
    com.apple.metadata:kMDItemWhereFroms       188 
    com.apple.quarantine        61 
-rw-r--r--@  1 me  staff      18 Feb  8 04:41 snippet-8.cgi
    com.apple.metadata:kMDItemDownloadedDate        53 
    com.apple.metadata:kMDItemWhereFroms       189 
    com.apple.quarantine        61 
    com.macromates.selectionRange        1 
    com.macromates.visibleIndex      1 
-rw-r--r--@  1 me  staff      18 Feb  8 04:37 snippet.cgi
    com.apple.metadata:kMDItemDownloadedDate        53 
    com.apple.metadata:kMDItemWhereFroms       189 
    com.apple.quarantine        61 

Here is curl -I http://www.cliftonchilliclub.co.uk
$curl -I http://www.cliftonchilliclub.co.uk
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Connection: close
Status: 200
X-Powered-By: Phusion Passenger (mod_rails/mod_rack) 2.2.5
X-Runtime: 9
ETag: "268dccda66a2552189bd2851a2f199a0"
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Content-Length: 852
Server: nginx/0.7.65 + Phusion Passenger 2.2.5 (mod_rails/mod_rack)
P3P: CP="IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT"
```

Quick trip with curl to download the file:

```
$curl -o file.html http://www.cliftonchilliclub.co.uk
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem at the web server end, most likely. This [meta-Google search link](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#es_th=1&q=snippet.cgi) will show you that the problem has existed for a while in many different places. Delve deeper & report back your findings.

**Note**: The cliftonchilliclub site [is mentioned](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3932308?tstart=0) at the Apple Support Communities as a site which triggers the same behavior you are experiencing.

All this being said, I believe the files are harmless.